# Android Wear Watchface and the WakeLock

Tags: android, wear-os, wakelock, android-wake-lock, watch-face-api

I'm developing a watchface for `Android Wear` using the `WatchFace API` (extending `CanvasWatchFaceService`).

I've used the code from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/drawing.html#Initialize) to build a ticker that run code **every second**.

I'm experiencing the following problem. Every now and then the service crashes with this exception. I can't understand where it comes from, if you have any lead I'll post additional code.

```
01-06 11:22:00.247  12965-12965/com.my.package E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.package, PID: 12965
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock.acquire()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceService$Engine.onCommand(WatchFaceService.java:201)
        at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.doCommand(WallpaperService.java:977)
        at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage(WallpaperService.java:1191)
        at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:37)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

After this crash the watchface stops working and to make it start again I have to choose another watchface, then reselect mine, so it's a total show stopper!

Comment: are you calling `acquire()` method in `WatchFaceService`?

Comment: Could you please post your code?
Somewhere you invoked the `acquire()` method of a WakeLock object which is not initialized.
On the site you referenced, no such thing happens.

Comment: Neither in my code, I also never use a WakeLock object.
I'm using an ObjectAnimator, could it be the cause?

Comment: I'm getting this same crash. Like you, my code never uses a WakeLock, and mine has no animators either.

Comment: FWIW, I've opened a bug report for this issue, at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=95740 . Please star.

Comment: Have you checked you have all the needed super.method(). 
I didn't have it on some methods and that was causing the crash.

Comment: David, I have now, and that was indeed the problem. I've added an answer to this question with my specific finding, though it's really your solution (if you'd rather write it up yourself for the mojo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Props to David for the lead on `super.` calls - it turns out that was the problem. Specifically, the `CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine.onCreate` method *needs* to call through to its ancestor, as such:

```
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);
        // your engine initialization code here
    }

    // other watch face engine code
}
```

Without the `super.onCreate(holder);` call, my watch face would crash within minutes; with it, it happily ran overnight.

As an aside, this is something missing from the Android developer documentation; specifically, the Training page for Building a Watch Face Service doesn't include this ancestor call in its code sample.

Comment: I have submitted a request to get the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/service.html#CallbackMethods changed. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I dug into the sample watch face code, as the docs suggest.  That's when I realized I too was missing calls to super.

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked lacks some important parts, that are dotted. I.e. have you defined the update rate?

```
private static final long INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);
```

Fully implemented it works well. See AnalogWatchFaceService in code samples: Wearable/Watchface face.

Comment: I already added this line in particular. I was missing some super. on overridden methods. I'm testing it right now.